# Automate font color depending on cell's background color brightness

Tags: excel, vba, colors, formatting

How can I create a macro in Excel that changes all font color to either black or white depending on cell's background color brightness (which can be any color Excel is capable of producing), with the objective being to maximize contrast between the font and cell's background colors?

Comment: "Is it possible" questions don't tend to do too well here. You may want to see [ask] and take the [tour]. SO is not really a code-writing site, but is for problems with existing code. This question is too broad.

Comment: Even if it is not a well asked question according [ask] I think answering this could be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved calculating the HSP model with the RGB values of the color. Therefore the `Interior.Color` value needs to be converted into Hex first to retrieve the decimal RGB values.

Then the brightness can becalculated with the formula

```
sqrt(0.299 * R² + 0.587 * G² + 0.114 * B²)
```

according to http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html and you can define a threshold which you consider as bright color or dark color eg using something like `If hsp > 127.5 Then`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    BlackWhiteFontColor Range("A1:A10")
End Sub

Public Sub BlackWhiteFontColor(ByRef FormatRange As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In FormatRange.Cells
        Dim Color As Long
        Color = Cell.Interior.Color
        
        'covert color into hex color
        Dim RGBHex As String
        RGBHex = Right$("000000" & Hex(Color), 6)
        
        'extract rgb values
        Dim Blue As Long, Green As Long, Red As Long
        Blue = CLng("&H" & Mid$(RGBHex, 1, 2))
        Green = CLng("&H" & Mid$(RGBHex, 3, 2))
        Red = CLng("&H" & Mid$(RGBHex, 5, 2))
        
        'calculate hsp according to http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html
        Dim hsp As Double
        hsp = Sqr(0.299 * (Red ^ 2) + 0.587 * (Green ^ 2) + 0.114 * (Blue ^ 2))
        
        If hsp > 127.5 Then
            'background color is light
            Cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
        Else
            'background color is dark
            Cell.Font.Color = vbWhite
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

[image]
*<sub>Image 1: Different background colors.</sub>*

[image]
*<sub>Image 2: Different background colors with either white or black font color depending on the brightness of the background.</sub>*

Comment: Love it, really helpful color model :+)

Answer (score 2):

Building on Pᴇʜ's excellent answer, you can make the text coloring a layer by utilising conditional formatting in addition to the calculated HSP value

> You can use the conditional formatting formula `=IsDark(A1)` {font color = white} in tandem with the following function to effect a similar coloring:

```
Public Function IsDark(ByRef Cell As Range) As Boolean
    If Cell.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim Blue As Long, Green As Long, Red As Long, PerceivedColor As Double
    
    Red = Cell.Interior.Color Mod 256
    Green = Cell.Interior.Color \ 256 Mod 256
    Blue = Cell.Interior.Color \ 65536 Mod 256
    PerceivedColor = 0.299 * (Red ^ 2) + 0.587 * (Green ^ 2) + 0.114 * (Blue ^ 2)
    IsDark = IIf(Sqr(PerceivedColor) > 127.5, False, True)
End Function
```

Comment: Ah well using the modulo is much easier than going through the hex as I did.  +1